# Weird session_start() error (key cannot be empty) for a specific client I can't reproduce

Tags: php, session, memcached

One specific user has been experiencing difficulties logging in to my site. He's getting the following error: `session_start(): Key cannot be empty`.

I have no idea what this error means, and haven't been able to identify why this happens only for a specific user. My session saving is handled through memcache.

What does the error mean? What can cause it only in a very specific case?

Answer (score 2):

This can often mean you're outputting something before the session_start, which shouldn't happen.

It could be a third party extension interfering with your page loading, I'd recommend the usual steps of use an incognito / private session, to see if problem persists. If not, it's a problem with his setup.

EDIT: However, this appears to be an [existing bug](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=59069)...

Comment: I didn't totally understand the bug workaround, and if what I'm experiencing is relevant. I should just try to add                     `if ($_GET[session_name()] == "") unset($_GET[session_name()]);` which should be a workaround if this is the bug?

Comment: Unfortunately bugs can be unpredictable. But yes, I'd give that a go, along with isset() in the if.